# Update with other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to update a column with an other column...

My code :

```
update Table1 set Table1.number = Table2.number from Table1 where Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id;
```

Error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from Table1 where Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI way to do this update is:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET     Table1.number = (   SELECT  Table2.number
                            FROM    Table2
                            WHERE   Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id
                        )
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  Table2.number
            FROM    Table2
            WHERE   Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id
        );
```

Or the proprietary MySQL UPDATE/JOIN syntax is:

```
UPDATE  Table1 
        INNER JOIN Table2
            ON Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id;
SET     Table1.number = Table2.number;
```

The ANSI syntax is pretty poor here, especially if you need to update multiple fields, something like:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET     Table1.number = (   SELECT  Table2.number
                            FROM    Table2
                            WHERE   Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id
                        ),
        Table1.number2 = (  SELECT  Table2.number2
                            FROM    Table2
                            WHERE   Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id
                        ),
        Table1.number3 = (  SELECT  Table2.number3
                            FROM    Table2
                            WHERE   Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id
                        )
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  Table2.number
            FROM    Table2
            WHERE   Table2.Table1Id= Table1.id
        );
```

I think even the most staunch of those that insist on ANSI compliant code would struggle to make a case for this over a simple join!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use `join` in the `update`:

```
update Table1 join
       Table2
       on Table2.Table1Id = Table1.id
    set Table1.number = Table2.number ;
```

This appears to be the intention of your syntax.